# SQL query to obtain last proximate occurrence of a row (by timestamp) with a particular property

Tags: mysql

This question is regarding a MySQL table.  Suppose you have a change log table, where reach row represents a change of a given type made on an object by a user. E.g., table named `changes`:

```
object_id   type    value   timestamp
1   UPDATE_NAME test1   1/1/15
1   UPDATE_SITE site1   1/1/15
1   ADD_BUDGET  $10 1/1/15
1   ADD_EXPENSE $5  1/1/15
1   UPDATE_TIME 10  1/20/15
1   UPDATE_TIME 8   1/31/15
2   UPDATE_NAME site2   1/2/15
2   REMOVE_BUDGET   $2  2/1/15
2   UPDATE_NAME newsite2    2/15/15
1   UPDATE_TIME 12  2/7/15
1   UPDATE_NAME newtest1    2/7/15
1   ADD_EXPENSE $4  2/7/15
```

Suppose I wanted to find any changes for object_id 1 on 2/7/15:

`select * from changes where object_id=1 and timestamp='2015-02-07';`

I would get back:

```
1   UPDATE_TIME 12  2/7/15
1   UPDATE_NAME newtest1    2/7/15
1   ADD_EXPENSE $4  2/7/15
```

Suppose now that I wanted to understand in a single query for any matching results, what is the last most proximate change for a matching `type` for the same object_id.  So, for example, while seeking the 3 rows in my above query for 2/7/2015, I'd like to also get back the following rows (in a single query):

```
1   UPDATE_TIME 8   1/31/15
1   UPDATE_NAME test1   1/1/15
1   ADD_EXPENSE $5  1/1/15
```

Why?  Because in my original query, I get these same change types back and I want to be able to compare them to the last changes of those types.  So, `1    UPDATE_TIME 8   1/31/15` is the last change of type UPDATE_TIME on object_id 1, `1  UPDATE_NAME test1   1/1/15` is the last change of type UPDATE_NAME on object_id 1, and `1   ADD_EXPENSE $5  1/1/15` is the last change of type ADD_EXPENSE on object_id 1.

So, in a single query, I'd like a clean list that shows the before and after values like this:

```
1   ADD_EXPENSE $4  2/7/15
1   ADD_EXPENSE $5  1/1/15
1   UPDATE_TIME 12  2/7/15
1   UPDATE_TIME 8   1/31/15
1   UPDATE_NAME newtest1    2/7/15
1   UPDATE_NAME test1   1/1/15
```

So, what I end up with is: gimme all changes that happened on object_id 1 on 2/7/2015 and show me the last value for each of those changes.  I can clearly see, for example, that when the TIME was updated on 2/7, it was updated from 8 to 12; similarly, when NAME was updated on 2/7, it was updated from test1 to newtest1.

**Considerations:**
- Would like to derive this final list in a single query...is it possible?
- Reminder: My only inputs are object_id and date. I have no idea how many rows will come back and of what type they will be.
- Just an fyi: there is the possibility that there is no previous change of that type.  I.e., the very first change of a particular type would not have a prior change of that type.  This is fine, just didn't know if it matters to the solution.
- object_id 2 is immaterial in my sample data.  Just added to demonstrate that there will be various other object_id's in the table.

### Update:

My original post was not clear.  I have updated the sample data and desired output to better illustrate the need.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is how you can see them per column (on the same line).

```
select l2.object_id, l2.type, l2.timestamp, l2.value, l3.timestamp, l3.value
from
(select l1.object_id, l1.type, l1.value, l1.timestamp  
 from Log l1 where l1.object_id=1 and l1.timestamp='2015-02-07') l2
left outer join Log l3 on (l3.object_id = l2.object_id and 
                           l3.type = l2.type and l3.timestamp=(select max(x.timestamp) 
                                                               from Log x 
                                                               where x.object_id=l2.object_id and
                                                                     x.type=l2.type and 
                                                                     x.timestamp<'2015-02-07'))
```

And this is how to see them as you want per line.

```
select l7.object_id, l7.type, l7.value, l7.timestamp
from 
(select l2.object_id, l2.type, l2.timestamp as timestamp1, l3.timestamp as timestamp2
from
(select l1.object_id, l1.type, l1.timestamp  
 from Log l1 where l1.object_id=1 and l1.timestamp='2015-02-07') l2
left outer join Log l3 on (l3.object_id = l2.object_id and 
                           l3.type = l2.type and l3.timestamp=(select max(x.timestamp) 
                                                               from Log x 
                                                               where x.object_id=l2.object_id and
                                                                     x.type=l2.type and 
                                                                     x.timestamp<'2015-02-07'))) f
inner join Log l7 on (l7.object_id=f.object_id and l7.type=f.type and
                     ((l7.timestamp=f.timestamp1) or (l7.timestamp=f.timestamp2))) 
order by l7.type, l7.timestamp
```

Comment: Okay, my original sample data and desired output wasn't clear.  I have updated it.  As you can see, it's a bit more complex.

Comment: You can. I'm not that good with mysql syntax but you definitely can. I will post a solution shortly.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked like a charm.  The initial query (l1) actually contained a join itself (values are technically stored in another table), so I reworked it a little and it's working as expected.  Thanks, especially, for your variation on showing old values by column...that layout is actually cleaner, so I went with it.  So helpful!

Comment: Still because this seems to be a large table (a log of every change) i recommend to use a stored procedure. It will run faster.